# Kinematics - Concept of average velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, speed

Average velocity, as I have heard, cannot be found simply by finding the average of two numbers. I have a question on average velocity, but am simply unable to proceed:

> *A particle moving in a straight line covers half the distance with speed of 3m/s. The other half of the distance is covered in two equal time intervals with speed 4.5m/s and 7.5m/s respectively. The average speed of the particle during this motion is?*

What I know: The average speed is the total distance divided by the total time
How exactly should I approach the question?

Comment: Have you tried finding the total distance and dividing by the total time?

Comment: Can't find the distance :(

Comment: you don't have to assume it any arbitrary variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v1=3, v2=4.5 , v3=7.5

let total distance be s

so average speed =total distance/total time.

total distance =s

time for 1st half distance = s/2/v1

for second half distance covered = s/2 =distance covered in 2 equal time intervals (say time interval be t)=t*4.5+t*7.5=t(4.5+7.5)=t(12)

so here t={s/2}/12

average speed={s}/[{s/2}/3+s/24+s/24]=s/{6s/24}=4m/s
since 2t was time for second journey

Comment: I think that's wrong, the answer is supposed to be 4 m/s

Comment: "total distance =s 

time for 1st half distance = s/v1" seems like typo, you need to divide s by 2.

Comment: you are right @Gummybears

Comment: Yeah, but that's cause I have the answer key. I don't get how to reach that answer. Using his method, I too reached the same answer :(

Comment: I have edited see.@Gummybears

Comment: Ohhhh!!!! I see the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can average the speeds in the second half, since they are for equal time intervals.

Let the total distance be a variable (d).

Solve for the time for each half segment, in terms of d.

Add the times together to get the total time.

Apply the definition you mention: "average speed is the total distance divided by the total time".

Comment: But for the second half, they are divided in terms of time! Please help!

Comment: I edited to explain more.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Pick a distance. It doesn't matter, it will divide out.  $45$ meters is handy.  Now calculat the total time required from the information given.  We know the first $22.5$ m was covered at $3$ m/sec, so how many seconds were required?  How many seconds are required for the other two pieces?  Now divide your distance by the total time.